# elasticsearch is not able to establish connection on ubuntu machine

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to run elastic search on my express/nodejs app on ubuntu 17.10. But somehow, it is giving the error as shown below:

```
Error: Request error, retrying
  HEAD http://localhost:9200/ => connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
```

My code for that is as shown below:

```
const connectElasticSearchClient = () => {
    client = new elasticsearch.Client({  
        hosts: ['localhost:9200'],
        maxRetries: 10,
        keepAlive: true,
        maxSockets: 10,
        minSockets: 10
    });

    client.ping({
        requestTimeout: 300000,
    }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('elasticsearch cluster is down!' + error);
        } else {
            console.log('Everything is ok');
        }
    });
};
```

I am trying to run it on node version `8.11.1`. The version of elasticsearch npm package is `13.3.1`.

Comment: does curling http://localhost:9200 work?

Comment: No, it is not working.